# How to get Subversion working in Solaris10 CSW Apache2

Tags: svn, apache2

Help I am pulling out my hair trying to get this combination to work. I have apache2 installed via CSW packages with subversion and the required CSWap2svn package. I have confirmed with `/opt/csw/apache2/sbin/apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` that the needed modules are loaded.

```
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_svn_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 authz_svn_module (shared)
```

I have modified my httpd.conf environment (actually httpd-vhosts.conf) and added the needed /location directive in the host local host vhost section (I have multiple vhosts).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/var/opt/webstack/apache2/2.2/htdocs/"
   ServerName qmysql1v
   Errorlog "/var/opt/webstack/apache2/2.2/logs/catchall-error_log"
   customLog "/var/opt/webstack/apache2/2.2/logs/catchall-access_log" common
   <IfModule dav_svn_module>
      <Location /subversion>
         DAV svn
         SVNPath /var/opt/webstack/subversion/repository
         AuthType Basic
         AuthName "ITD Repository"
         AuthUserFile /var/opt/webstack/subversion/repository/conf/svn-auth-file
         Require valid-user
      </Location>
   </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

the repository directories are create with `svnadmin create -fs-type fsfs /var/opt/webstack/subversion/repository`:

```
@QMYSQL1V# ls /var/opt/webstack/subversion/repository
conf        db          format      hooks       locks       README.txt
```

everything is set, however when to go to my browser to the url `http://qmysql1v/subversion` I get nothing. (url is local to my network no need to try and use it)

Log Files show:

> [Tue Nov 20 20:33:10 2012] [error] [client 172.18.10.14] File does not exist: /var/opt/webstack/apache2/2.2/htdocs/subversion

Keep in mind from what i have read, the repository doesn't need to be in the document root of the vhost/apache2 server. Help!